# Mysql inner join multiple word search

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have table structure:

- lnks(l_id,txt,url,name) - l_id is link id unique
- kws(wrd, kw_id) - as dictionary, wrd is the word, id is unique
- kwds0..kwds21 - words, relation kws.kw_id->lnks.l_id 
  (keyword(many))->link_ids
- I am doing a multiple word search for "word word2". The words table
  pre-key is  calculated in code and I have them as kwds12 and kwds13.
- I try to get all the links which have all the words in the query.
  'word1' is in table kwds12    'word2' is in table kwds13

---

```
SELECT
    url,
    name
FROM
    lnks  
    INNER JOIN kwds12, kwds13
        ON   
            lnks.l_id=kwds12.l_id
                AND
            lnks.l_id=kwds13.l_id
    INNER JOIN kws
        ON   
            kws.kw_id=kwds12.kw_id
                OR
            kws.kw_id=kwds13.kw_id
WHERE   
    kws.wrd='word1'
        OR
    kws.wrd='word2'
```

---

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON lnks.l_id=kwds12.l_id AND lnks.l_id=kwds13.l_id INNER JOIN kws ON kws.kw_id=' at line 2

Thx

Comment: The error is in the syntax of the query, table structure is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is in the first `INNER JOIN`:

```
INNER JOIN kwds12, kwds13 ...
```

That comma must not be there. If you are using `INNER JOIN`, then you need to join tables separately (you cannot separate tables with commas).

If you need to, you can substitute all your joins with `where` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This should work better. You need to join every table for itself.

```
SELECT
    url,
    name
FROM
    lnks  
    INNER JOIN kwds12
        ON   
            lnks.l_id=kwds12.l_id
    INNER JOIN kwds13
        ON   
            lnks.l_id=kwds13.l_id
    INNER JOIN kws
        ON   
            kws.kw_id=kwds12.kw_id
                OR
            kws.kw_id=kwds13.kw_id
WHERE   
    kws.wrd='word1'
        OR
    kws.wrd='word2'
```